# Смещение строки "назад"

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++, замена

Пытаюсь отредактировать текст с помощью Notepad++ используя регулярные выражения.
В интернете я нашел много объяснений тому, как работает ПОИСК, но в данном случае мне нужна ЗАМЕНА, замена со смещением. Я понимаю как найти каждую строку начинающуюся НЕ с цифры (таймкода), а именно ^[^0-9].

Но вот как ее сместить в конец предыдущей строки?

Исходный текст:

```
00:00:53,971 --> 00:00:58 With every sun comes a new day.
A new beginning.
00:00:58,850 --> 00:01:02 A hope that things will be better today
than they were yesterday.
00:01:03,522 --> 00:01:06 But not for me.
My name is Eep.
00:01:06,316 --> 00:01:09 And this is my family, the Croods.
00:01:09,611 --> 00:01:11 If you weren't clued in already by the
animal skins
```

Желаемый результат:

```
00:00:53,971 --> 00:00:58 With every sun comes a new day. A new beginning.
00:00:58,850 --> 00:01:02 A hope that things will be better today than they were yesterday.
00:01:03,522 --> 00:01:06 But not for me. My name is Eep.
00:01:06,316 --> 00:01:09 And this is my family, the Croods.
00:01:09,611 --> 00:01:11 If you weren't clued in already by the animal skins
```

Comment: Сначала расширенным поиском уберите все переводы строк, а потом регуляркой вставьте их перед штампами времени.

Comment: Найти: `^([0-9].*)\s+(^[^0-9].*)` заменить: `$1 $2` Попробуйте так

Comment: @Akina да, так можно, но в том все и дело, что я не знаю как задать это самое смещение (шаг вперед/назад) ДО найденного или ПОСЛЕ найденного. У меня получается лишь заменить найденное, а я планирую сохранить найденное.

Comment: Искомую группу оборачиваете скобками. В поле замены подставляете порядковый номер скобки со знаком доллара (см. коммент от @PotroNik). *В интернете я нашел много объяснений тому как работает ПОИСК, но в данном случае мне нужна ЗАМЕНА* Попробуйте почитать справку к программе, что ли... https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/

Comment: @PotroNik да, это действительно решение. Часто вижу в ответах к разным вопросам, в поле замена стоит $1 $2 и т.д. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем смысл этих сочетаний?

Comment: @untitledcustom, `$1` или `\1` - это значение захваченное группой захвата регулярного выражения, в данном случае `^([0-9].*)` строка где вначале будет цифра, а далее любое количество любых символов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В поле найти:

```
\s+(?=^[^0-9])
```

В поле заменить на:
  - пробел

[image: Настройки окна замены]

Логика работы:
`[\s]+` - один и более символов перевода строки или иных пробельных символов
`(?=^[^0-9])` - позитивный просмотр вперед, где в начале строки нет цифры